# C# Use returned value from Method in IF/ELSE Statement

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, syntax

Right now I am working on a simple program, and this is a problem I've been thinking over many times. Many times I run my methods twice because of checking on the return value before running them, and I would like to know if there is a way I can prevent this, like using the returned value from the method I am checking against. It's quite hard to explain so here is a real life example from my program.

```
public class SFDBRepository
{
    public static Domain.SF.SFObject GetSFOrder(string WorkOrd)
    {
        //As you can see here i'm checking on the output of this method, before trying to return it.
        if (Domain.SF.SF.GetOrder(WorkOrd) != null)
        {
            //If the value is not null (My method returns null if no result), return the object
            return Domain.SF.SF.GetOrder(WorkOrd);
        }
        //Same thing happens here. My method runs twice every time almost. 
        else if(Domain.Building_DeliveryPerformance.Building_DeliveryPerformance.GetObject(WorkOrd) != null)
        {
            return Domain.Building_DeliveryPerformance.Building_DeliveryPerformance.GetObject(WorkOrd);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Capture the return value into a variable, use the variable thereafter:  `var result = Domain.ShopFloor.Shopfloor.GetOrder(WorkOrd) ... if (result != null) return result;`

Comment: You should also consider the [`using` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) so you don't have to use the entire namespace paths repeatedly in your code.  Also best practice is to not name classes the same as the namespace that they are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Domain.ShopFloor.ShopFloorObject GetShopFloorOrder(string WorkOrd)
{
    //As you can see here i'm checking on the output of this method, before trying to return it.
    Domain.ShopFloor.ShopFloorObject wo = Domain.ShopFloor.Shopfloor.GetOrder(WorkOrd);
    if (wo != null)
    {
        //If the value is not null (My method returns null if no result), return the object
        return wo;
    }
    //Same thing happens here. My method runs twice every time almost. 
    Domain.ShopFloor.ShopFloorObject yowo = Domain.DG9_DeliveryPerformance.DG9_DeliveryPerformance.GetObject(WorkOrd);
    if(yowo != null)
    {
        return yowo;
    }

    /* default return */
    return null;

}
```

PS

You're kinda doing the "Factory Pattern"

See

http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

Comment: This code won't even compile because you have put a line of code which sits before the "else if" statement, but outside the curly brackets of the body of the first "if" branch ...

Comment: The last two clauses are redundant: you have if it is not null, return it, if it is null, return null. How is that any different from simply 'return it", regardless of its nullity?

Comment: Because the first test returns if true, neither the original code nor this needs `else if`... and as @EricLippert points out, the whole of the second half could just be replaced with `return Domain.DG9_DeliveryPerformance.DG9_DeliveryPerformance.GetObject(WorkOrd);`

Comment: I fixed the code.  I was trying to push the idea the OP needed.  Which I think he/she got.

Comment: This code is not the most minimal code.  see @JamesHarcourt for that.  However, this is the most readable and debug friendly version, IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify this down to the following code, which will only call those methods once and make the code much more readable:

```
public class ShopFloorDBRepository
{
    public static Domain.ShopFloor.ShopFloorObject GetShopFloorOrder(string workOrd)
    {
        return Domain.ShopFloor.Shopfloor.GetOrder(workOrd) ??
               Domain.DG9_DeliveryPerformance.DG9_DeliveryPerformance.GetObject(workOrd);
    }
}
```

To explain why this works - the ?? operator (the null-coalescing operator!) basically says "if the returned value on the left hand side of the ?? is null, then return the value of the expression on the right hand side".

This way you only need to call your functions once.

Comment: Obviously the questioner is relatively new to c#, so a short description of what you're doing here with the ?? operator, and why there is no need to return an explicit null would also probably help.

Comment: @PaulG updated the answer to explain the null coalesce operator usage

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like you could be using a temporary variable to hold the result, which you can test and return.

```
public class ShopFloorDBRepository
{
  public static Domain.ShopFloor.ShopFloorObject GetShopFloorOrder(string WorkOrd)
  {
    var result = Domain.ShopFloor.GetOrder(WorkOrd);

    if (result != null) return result;
    ...
```

This is a common paradigm, especially when the method being called is expensive and/or has side effects you don't wish to incur twice.

Here, the "var" declaration sets the type of "result" to the type returned by the method being called; you could also use the name of the actual type.

If you wish to make two different kinds of tests like this, you'll need two different variables unless they have the same type (which in this case it appears they do).

An alternate mechanism that does require the full type, that you'll also see:

```
public static ShopFloorObject GetShopFloorOrder(string WorkOrd)
{
    ShopFloorObject result;

    if ( (result = Domain.ShopFloor.GetOrder(WorkOrd)) != null )
        return result;
    if ( (result = Domain.DG9_DeliveryPerformance.DG9_DeliveryPerformance.GetObject(WorkOrd)) != null)
        return result;
    return null;
```

Here you're explicitly declaring the type of the return value, then making the two calls you've indicated, testing the results against null, and returning the first non-null value.